# How to remove special characters from input text box and display in a label?

Tags: c#

create a project that will allow the user to enter a mailing address. The address may not contain any leading or trailing spacebars and may not contain the following special characters.

```
•   Period key (.)
•   Comma (,)
•   Semicolon (;)
```

The user will enter a mailing address into a Text Box. When the appropriate button is selected, the entered address will be checked for any invalid characters. The resulting/corrected address will then be displayed into a Label.

I have written code but I cannot figure out how to display it in the label box without the period, comma, and semicolon

I have tried several ways to display the text but nothing has warranted the correct output

```
string wordString;
            char[] delimChar = { ',', '.', ';' };

            wordString = entryTextBox.Text;
            wordString = wordString.Trim();
            string[] delimString = wordString.Split(delimChar);
```

I have no error messages in the code but need some additional help.

Answer (score 3):

Please try given below. Thanks.

```
string inputValue = textBox1.Text
                    .Trim()
                    .Replace(".", "")
                    .Replace(",", "")
                    .Replace(";", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic number of chars, just loop the replacement:

```
char[] delimChar = { ',', '.', ';' };
var labelBuilder = new StringBuilder(textBox1.Text);
foreach(var c in delimChar) 
  labelBuilder.Replace(c, string.Empty);

label1.Text = labelBuilder.ToString().Trim();
```

Or you may still use [Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
var label = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "[,.;]", string.Empty).Trim();
```

I'd also recommend to trim string after replacement to handle cases like `PO 145   ;`

Comment: This worked as well. Thank you for your contribution!